# pass htaccess login/pwd with watir webdriver

Tags: .htaccess, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm writing step definitions for my cucumber scenario's. But the test website is protected with htaccess login/password.

I know how to get the elements from HTML. But how do I pass this hurdle with watir webdriver?

Actually found the answer myself:

http://login:password@www.somewhere.com

Comment: You could enter the answer yourself as an answer and accept it. That helps people looking for answers later on, as it shows an answered question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> http://username:password@www.yoursite.com

Answer (score 0):

I have special chars in the passwort and got the error:

```
(NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

What helped was to encode the whole URL like:

```
browser.goto URI.escape('http://user:!super#secure@url.com')
```